# Tensor Product of Abelian Groups and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just finished my first abstract algebra course but the last lesson about tensor product was too much to me. So I am reading again about that stuff and cross by with a problem related with finding an isomorphism between product tensor: (X,Y,Z abelian groups)

1) $ X\cong \Bbb Z\otimes X$

2)$ X\otimes Y \cong Y \otimes X$

3) $X\otimes (Y\otimes Z) \cong X\otimes Y \otimes Z$

1) In this one I am not quite sure why this shoul be true if we are adding a whole new set...

2) In this one I think just need to take the map $f: X\otimes Y \to Y \otimes X$ by letting $f(x\otimes y)= (y\otimes x)$ and see that $f$ is an isomorphism.

3) This one is more easy to "see" is true but I am not quite sure how to prove it.

Thanks for your patience and hope you could help a little bit.

I am going to write the definition of tensor product as I was told.

Let $ X$ and $Y$ be abelian groups. The tensor product of $X$ and $Y$ is the pair ($T$,$f$) where $T$ is an abelian group and $f:X\times Y\to T$ is an additive map, such that if $G$ is an abelian group and $g: X\times Y\to G$ is an additive then there is only one homomorphism $h:T\to G$ such that $g=h\circ f$

Edit: checking out more information about Tensor product I found out that we can define $X\otimes Y$ as the elements $x\otimes y$ with $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ such that

$$ (x_1 + x_2)\otimes y= x_1\otimes y + x_2\otimes y$$
$$ x\otimes (y_1 + y_2)= x\otimes y_1 + x\otimes y_2$$

and if $\lambda \in \Bbb Z$ we got:
$$(\lambda x)\otimes y=\lambda (x\otimes y)=x\otimes (\lambda y)$$

This way gotta be much easier....

Comment: You do seem to have a misunderstanding of what the tensor product is. It is not a set of ordered pairs, rather it is generated by them.

Comment: My mistake, I define f wrong, rather than a order pairs I should wrote it as the classes generated by them

Comment: The tensor product $\mathbf Z \otimes X$ is *not* $\mathbf Z \times X$; you are not just "adding a whole new set" but also imposing *relations* among elementary tensors that collapses stuff too.   See Theorems 4.5, 5.1, and 5.2 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf (using the ring $R = \mathbf Z$).

Comment: Maybe I should not write an "abstract algebra course" it was more like an introudction to abstract algebra. We just saw groups, free groups and elementary stuff